# any automated way of checking for redundant javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gruntjs

I'm just wrapping up a template for the company I work for and whilst JSLint is pretty effective at highlighting code that can be improved or changed, there are the odd bits here and there that I noticed JSLint doesn't pick up.

I was wondering if there are any tools that you can use that highlight redundant code? like an "un-css" for javascript?

Thanks

Comment: There is Rollup, which performs tree-shaking on ES6 modules, and UglifyJS removes things like unused variables.

Comment: What IDE are using and what kind of odd bits are we talking about? IntelliSense in JetBrain's WebStorm/PhpStorm can track silly or pointless code pretty well.

Comment: I'm using Atom, one example of something redundant I found was 

var item = _.find(this.data.items, function (item) {
            if (_.indexOf(item.link, e.index) !== -1) {
                return true;
            }
        }, this);

There was no need to bind "this". It's those sort of things which are easy to miss which I'd like to be able to sweep my script for.